# AutocompleteTextView suggestions always selecting the first item in suggestions

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-filterable

I'm facing an issue that I cannot solve. I have created an AutoCompleteTextView that displays filtered suggestions from remote JSON data. The suggestions box pops up fine and filters properly. I have two issues which I cannot understand.

1. When selecting the suggestion item the text in the
   AutoCompleteTextView it's always set to the first item in the original
   suggestions array, whether the data is filtered or not.
2. When deleting characters in the AutocompleteTextview, if it becomes
   empty a null pointer exception is thrown

**The code of my custom adapter:**

```
package tz.co.fsm.fas;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class office_locations_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<office_location_data> implements Filterable {
    private Context context;
    private List<office_location_data> items, tempItems, suggestions;
    int row_layout;

    public office_locations_adapter(Context context, int row_layout, List<office_location_data> items) {
        super(context, row_layout, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.row_layout = row_layout;
        this.items = items;
        tempItems = new ArrayList<>(items); 
        suggestions = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(row_layout, parent, false);
        }

        office_location_data office = items.get(position);

        if (office != null) {
            TextView lbloffice = view.findViewById(R.id.rowtxtOfficeLocation);
            if (lbloffice != null) {
                lbloffice.setText(office.getOffice_location());
            }
        }

        return view;
    }

    // This is important as it returns the count of the new arraylist when we filter it.
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    // Method to return the filter
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return performFiletring;
    }

    // Create a new filter. Here we perform the filtering results and use this in the getFilter() method
    Filter performFiletring = new Filter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
            String str = ((office_location_data) resultValue).getOffice_location();
            return str;
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            // We have some text to search
            if (constraint != null) {
                // CLear the suggestions array
                suggestions.clear();
                // Find the rows which match and add them to suggestions
                for (office_location_data offices : tempItems) {
                    if (offices.getOffice_location().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        suggestions.add(offices);
                    }
                }
                // Pass the filter results to the next step publish results
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = suggestions;
                filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
//                System.out.println(filterResults.count);
                return filterResults;
            } else {
                return new FilterResults();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            items = (List) results.values;
            if (results.count > 0) {
                //suggestions = (office_location_data) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. The `publishResults()` method was wrong:

```
@Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            List<office_location_data> items = (ArrayList<office_location_data>) results.values;
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                clear();
                for (office_location_data offices : suggestions) {
                    add(offices);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
```

This is how I did it.